# Is ため always 尾高?

Tags: pitch-accent

Even ための？ For example is pronouncing the following sentence like this correct
旅行ため\の準\備
or is it just 旅行ための準\備

Comment: It's 旅行**の**ための準備. In some cases you could say 旅行用 but not here

Comment: I think の should be treated differently from other particles. It works within a noun phrase and may stay high when the noun phrase is said in one go.